# Autoscaling DC/OS agents on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dcos

We have DC/OS running on AWS with a fixed number of master nodes and agent nodes as part of a POC. However, we'd like to have the cluster (agent nodes) autoscale according to load. So far, we've been unable to find any information about scaling on DC/OS docs. I've also had no luck so far in my web-searches.

If someone's got this working already, please let us know how you did it.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Autoscaling the number of service instances by cpu, memory, or network load is possible: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/tutorials/autoscaling/

Autoscaling the number of DC/OS nodes by adding/removing nodes, however, is outside of the scope of DC/OS and specific to the IaaS it is deployed on. You can imagine that this wouldn't work on bare metal for obvious reasons. It's hypothetically possible, of course, but I haven't seen any existing automation for it.

The DC/OS AWS templates use easily scaled node groups, but it's not automatic. You might try looking for IaaS specific autoscalers that aren't DC/OS specific.

Comment: The autoscaling mentioned in that link is scaling the allocation of resources for applications (or containers) running in the DC/OS cluster.

Autoscaling the number of nodes should really be within the DC/OS scope for the same reason that cloud providers have autoscaling - dynamically scale according to load.

In fact, "Docker for AWS" seems to have this functionality. New instances added to the autoscaling group are automatically added to the Docker Swarm.

Comment: If you deploy DC/OS on AWS you can use autoscaling groups the same way. But it's not fully auto if you have to adjust the number up and down manually. It's only auto from the perspective that it brings up provisioned nodes that auto-add to the DC/OS cluster.

Comment: can you please point me to a document or website URL that can help me further with setting up this auto-addition of provisioned nodes to the DC/OS cluster? 

Thank you!

Comment: The DC/OS AWS CloudFormation templates create Auto Scaling Groups that can be manually or dynamically scaled: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the cloudformation templates creates a new VPC and associated subnets instead of using my own. 

There is , one CF template, that will take your VPC and subnets as parameters to install DC/OS, but I noticed that it changes the routing tables of any subnet you provide. Not ideal either.

Comment: The CF template generation is open source. Feel free to submit modifications that add configurability.

Comment: Cool. I'll see what I can do. I suck with CF so it's going to be a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an autoscaling group for your "private agent" nodes and you want to scale the number of nodes in times of heavy load, pick a CloudWatch metric that suits your needs (e.g. traffic on ELB) and scale by an autoscaling scaling policy:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/policy_creating.html
Then you can use one of the two ways described in https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/tutorials/autoscaling/ to scale your apps within DC/OS (on scheduler level).